# Android: LayoutHeight don't update

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a ConstraintLayout A which can be opened/close and contains some cards that have a ConstraintLayout B inside them that can be visible or not. When I close A (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`) firstly I close all B inside A then do A close animation, but I noticed that A.getHeight() return a value as all of the B inside are visible so the closing animation isn't right. How can I fix this?

*(holder.linearLayout is A, l is B)*

Both 2 logs print same value, but the UI changes correctly if I comment the animation.

```
// Close all open children
            Log.d(TAG, ">>Height:" + holder.linearLayout.getHeight());

            int numberOfChildren = holder.linearLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i) {
                View v = holder.linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                ConstraintLayout l = v.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_card);
                l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, ">>Height:" + holder.linearLayout.getHeight());
            
            AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
            Animation animationAlpha = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
            animation.addAnimation(animationAlpha);
            Animation animationTranslate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -holder.linearLayout.getHeight());
            animation.addAnimation(animationTranslate);
            Animation animationY = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 1, 0);
            animationY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animation.addAnimation(animationY);
            animation.setDuration(250);

            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            holder.linearLayout.startAnimation(animation);
            holder.isOpen = false;
```

Comment: Your A.getHeight() will return value as you are only translating the position of view from (0,0) to (0, -height_of_layout). Even thought the views would be out of sight because they are either out of screen display area or hidden under some other view but they will still have height.

Comment: But documentation says:
View.GONE: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: Oh I missed the View.GONE in the onAnimationEnd() method by the way you are measuring height after for loop on children you should measure it in the onAnimationEnd() method after applying View.GONE to holder.linearLayout

Comment: The height is needed for doing animation, to do the right traslation